# How do I get the value inside a div which is dynamically generated via an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Basically, the current weather is displayed on our page via a weather API.

What I'd like to do is to capture the data (say, 29 degree celsius) and create conditions for it using javascript. Like, if it's 25-29 degreee celsius, a sunny icon will appear (otherwise, another icon should be shown).

However, when I try to capture the data, the console says "empty string", although the data is visible on the page. How do I go about this so that the dynamic data is captured?

```
<div class="weather">
[DYNAMICALLY WEATHER IS DISPLAYED HERE]
</div>    

$(document).ready(function() {
      $.simpleWeather({
        location: 'Singapore, SG',
        woeid: '',
        unit: 'c',
        success: function(weather) {
          html = '<p class="widget-weather-info-temp"> '+weather.temp+'<sup class="widget-weather-deg">&deg;</sup><sup class="widget-weather-unit-temp">'+weather.units.temp+'</sup></p>';

          $("#weather").html(html);
        },
        error: function(error) {
          $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
        }
      });
    });


    var $widgetInfoTemp = $(".widget-weather-info-temp").text();
    console.log($widgetInfoTemp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all your logic in the success function after the html append

```
 success: function(weather) {
          html = '<p class="widget-weather-info-temp"> '+weather.temp+'<sup class="widget-weather-deg">&deg;</sup><sup class="widget-weather-unit-temp">'+weather.units.temp+'</sup></p>';

          $("#weather").html(html);

    var $widgetInfoTemp = $(".widget-weather-info-temp").text();
    console.log($widgetInfoTemp);
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to the API is asynchronous, so you need to place your `console.log()` inside the `success` handler function. When doing that you don't need to request the element from the DOM as you already have access to the returned data. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.simpleWeather({
        location: 'Singapore, SG',
        woeid: '',
        unit: 'c',
        success: function(weather) {
            html = '<p class="widget-weather-info-temp">' + weather.temp + '<sup class="widget-weather-deg">&deg;</sup><sup class="widget-weather-unit-temp">' + weather.units.temp + '</sup></p>';
            $("#weather").html(html);

            // work with the weather data here...
            console.log(weather);
            console.log(weather.temp);
            console.log(weather.units.temp);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            $("#weather").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```